# Need help to create Terraform code where user has an option to create Azure VM from Marketplace image or specify a custom VHD from Storage Account

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

We have a very specific requirement where some of the Vendors provides their images from Azure Marketplace and some just provide the .vhd

I need to build a terraform code where user should have an option to either create a VM based out of Azure Marketplace image, or he should be able provide **source_uri** of the VHD to create a VM.
For now I have the codes ready to create a VM from .vdh file,

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "this" {
  name                              = var.name
  location                          = var.location
  resource_group_name               = var.resource_group_name
  vm_size                           = var.size
  network_interface_ids             = [azurerm_network_interface.this.id]
  delete_os_disk_on_termination     = true
  delete_data_disks_on_termination  = true
  tags                              = var.tags
  availability_set_id               = var.availability_set_id == "" ? null : var.availability_set_id

resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "os" {
  name                  = var.os_disk_name
  location             = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  os_type              = "Linux"
  storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS" 
  create_option        = "Import"
  storage_account_id   = var.storage_account_id
  source_uri           = var.source_uri
  disk_size_gb         = var.disk_size_gb
}

  
  # attach the managed disk, created from the imported vhd.
  storage_os_disk {
    name              = join("", [var.name, "-", var.os_disk_name])
    os_type           = "Linux"
    managed_disk_id   = azurerm_managed_disk.os.id
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "Attach"
  }

  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = false
  }
}
```

The default option should be spin up a VM from Azure Marketplace. Can this be archived via **variables**

Comment: Yes, you can setup conditional resource creation based on input variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the list of VM's image based on publishers available in the Azure Marketplace.

```
az vm image list --output table --all --publisher center-for-internet-security-inc.
```

I am taking the below image from Azure MarketPlace as a reference:

[image]

You can find your images based on offer, SKU, Publisher on your requirement. Refer to this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/image?view=azure-cli-latest) for more info.

You can use this terraform code to create Azure VM from Marketplace image:

***main.tf***

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features{}
}


data "azurerm_resource_group" "main" {
  name     = "${var.resource_group_name}"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "main" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "internal" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.main.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-nic"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "testconfiguration1"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.internal.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "main" {
  name                  = "${var.prefix}-vm"
  location              = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name   = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.main.id]
  admin_username      = "adminuser"
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"

  # Uncomment this line to delete the OS disk automatically when deleting the VM
  # delete_os_disk_on_termination = true

  # Uncomment this line to delete the data disks automatically when deleting the VM
  # delete_data_disks_on_termination = true
storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "${var.publisher}"
    offer = "${var.offer}"
    sku = "${var.sku}"
    version = "${var.version1}"
}

plan {
    publisher = "${var.publisher}"
    product = "${var.offer}"
    name = "cis-ubuntu2004-l1""
}
  
 storage_os_disk {
    name              = "myosdisk1"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }
  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "hostname"
    admin_username = "testadmin"
    admin_password = "Password1234!"
  }
  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = false
  }

  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
 
}
```

***variable.tf***

```
variable "resource_group_name" {
  default = "v-XXXXX-XXXXX"
}

variable "prefix" {
  default = "tfvmex"
}

variable "publisher" {
  default="center-for-internet-security-inc"
}
variable "offer" {
  default = "cis-ubuntu-linux-2004-l1"
}

variable "sku" {
  default = "cis-ubuntu2004-l1povw"
}

variable "version1" {
  default="1.1.9"
}
```

Due to somepolicy appiled in my subscription so i am not able to test it but yes you can test  in your enviorment.

You can refer this [document](https://blog.edgeitc.com/posts/deploy-vm-azuremarketplace-terraform.html) for the same requirement.